# Drivers on my Dell Laptop

Tags: windows, networking, drivers

Today I installed Windows Server 2008 on my old dell inspiron 8200. I was having some issues because I could not connect to the internet.

**OFF TOPIC** I am new so I have no idea where do I ask this question.

I searched on google for network controller driver for dell inspiron 8200, and I also tried to configure my 802.11n wireless adapter. But every single driver I try to install, it still does not work. Later today I found a Dell Inspiron CD and tried to find a driver on it but I was unsuccessful. So my question is, where can I find a Network driver for my laptop running Windows Server 2008 and pls make it quick.

**Maybe OFF TOPIC** My computer is running a 32bit version. Also just a random question, is there a way to run Windows Server 2012 on it. I know there are only 64bit versions, but where can I find a 32bit version.

Comment: You can try going to [Dell Support](http://www.dell.com/support/) and enter the service tag of the machine to find the appropriate drivers. "I know there are only 64bit versions, but where can I find a 32bit version." - Huh? As you say Windows Server 2012 is only available in 64-bit versions, so you won't find a 32-bit version.

Comment: You can start from here http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-8200/drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what specific network card you have in the system, this is the best I can provide: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-8200/drivers

Also, this system doesn't use a 64-bit processor, nor does it support the RAM requirements of at least 4GB for any 64-bit Windows Operating System. So no, it would not support Server 2012.

An alternate solution would be to obtain a USB network adapter complete with drivers and install it on the system, making sure the OS is supported before you buy the adapter.

Comment: Is there a way to find out, i have been installing drivers all day. I think this may work but idk, http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=X2WM7